# Coin flipping and probability

Tags: probability, statistics

One in each two people launches three equilibrated coins. How likely is it that take the same number of heads???

guy $1$, just head $1/2 \cdot 1/2\cdot 1/2= 1/8$

guy $2$, just head $= 1/8$

But how likely is it that take the same number of heads? I have no idea how to work with it... could you help me?

Comment: Hint: $0$ heads and $0$ heads **or** $1$ head and $1$ head **or** $\dots$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split it into **disjoint** events, and sum up their probabilities:

- The probability that they both get $0$ head is $\frac18\cdot\frac18=\frac{1}{64}$
- The probability that they both get $1$ head is $\frac38\cdot\frac38=\frac{9}{64}$
- The probability that they both get $2$ head is $\frac38\cdot\frac38=\frac{9}{64}$
- The probability that they both get $3$ head is $\frac18\cdot\frac18=\frac{1}{64}$

So the probability that they get the same number of heads is $\frac{1}{64}+\frac{9}{64}+\frac{9}{64}+\frac{1}{64}=\frac{20}{64}$